# Palindrome program - string index out of range exception

Tags: java, string, exception, palindrome

I've written code for my CS class to identify if a user inputted string is a palindrome or not. I've gotten the code to work. However, whenever I execute the code I get this message:

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at palindrome.Palindrome.main(Palindrome.java:14)"
```

I think there's something wrong with my `length` and `i` but I'm not sure what. My code is below. I used `aabbaa` for the user inputted string.

```
package palindrome;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Palindrome {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println ("Enter A String:");
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        String s = input.nextLine();
        int length = s.length();
        int i = 0;
        while (length>= 0) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(length-1)) { 
                i++;
                length--;
                if (length == i) {
                    System.out.println ("Your string is a palindrome");
                    length = 0;
                }
            }
            else {
                System.out.println ("Your string is not a palindrome");
                length = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just curious @downvoter, as to why this post was downvoted?

Comment: Nitpick - if it is throwing exceptions, you haven't got it to work.  You've got it to compile, and in a sense you've got it to run.  But it is NOT working in the normal sense of "working".

Answer (score 2):

When length equals 0, the first if-statement in your while loop tries to get s.charAt(0-1), i.e. s.charAt(-1), which is where the error occurs.

Perhaps try the following (not tested):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println ("Enter A String:");
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
String s = input.nextLine();
int length = s.length();
int i = 0;
while (length > 0) {
    if (s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(length-1)) { 
        i++;
        length--;
        if (length < 1) {
            System.out.println ("Your string is a palindrome");
            break;
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println ("Your string is not a palindrome");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh ok. That makes sense. I never considered that the length could equal zero. Thanks. Your explanation was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You write `while(length >= 0) {}` and in the `main` method you write `length = 0;` trying to the loop.

That should be `while(length > 0){}`

Answer (score 1):

Just create a method like below and pass your string as argument to test whether string is a palindrome or not. Method will return true in case of string is palindrome

Idea is reverse your string and compare with original string if both are same then it is a palindrome.

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String str) {
    return str.equals(new StringBuffer().append(str).reverse().toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that in every step you take two strides, but only decrease length by 1

So a trace: A user enters `foooof`.

```
length = 6
i = 0
f == f
i = 1
length = 5
o == o
i = 2
length = 4
o == o
i = 3
length = 3 (You've now passed yourself)
o == o
i = 4
length = 2
length-i = -2 =>     index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

When you iterate the while loop at that time value of length becomes negative, and array index starts from `0` thats why you getting the exception as `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

You should try this, it will works fine.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Palindrome
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter A String:");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = input.nextLine();
        int length = s.length();
        int i = 0;
        while (length >= 0)
        {
            if (s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(length - 1))
            {
                i++;
                length--;
                if (length-1 == i)
                {
                    System.out.println("Your string is a palindrome");
                    length = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Your string is not a palindrome");
                length = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do some thing like this:

```
package palindrome;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Palindrome {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println ("Enter A String:");
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        String s = input.nextLine();
        if ( s.equals(new StringBuffer(s).reverse().toString()) ){
            System.out.println ("Your string is a palindrome");
        else
            System.out.println ("Your string is not a palindrome");
    }
}
```